# How do I call a custom class in the cakephp framework

Tags: php

I am new to cakePHP,

I have write a class in MODEL with name of myClass() and I have one function like func().

**CODE:**

```
class myClass(){
    function func(){
        echo "test";
    }

}
```

But I don't know how to call the "myClass class" and run the function func() in the controller file in the cakePHP framework.

Can any one help me.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once(PATH_TO_MODEL.'model.php'); // might not be needed
$myclass = new myClass();
$myclass->func();
```

Check out http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php for the comment about require_once not being needed